# Polyline not connecting to first point

Tags: swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I'm declaring a point like so

```
makeAnnotation(givenTitle: "Start", pointCoords: userCoords)
turnLocations.append(userCoords)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userCoords, latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

`userCoords` is being set right, and the title "Start" appears on the map without the annotation pin visual, although it does zoom to it properly with the region. When I calculate the distance between this "Start" and my other annotations and add them together, it works properly, and even regonizes the starting route. However, when I make a polyline like this: (and render it properly)

```
let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: turnLocations, count: turnLocations.count) //makes polyLine w/ coords given
mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
```

It only makes a polyline between every other point in the `turnLocations` array or connects it weird like this (it should connect to turn1)

[image: https://imgur.com/a/kP3wbWc]

**Edit: Since I was asked, here is how other coordinates in turnLocations are added:**

```
let coords = mapView.convert(tapLocation,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
print("Tapped at lat: \(coords.latitude) long: \(coords.longitude)")
makeAnnotation(givenTitle: "Turn\(annotations.count)", pointCoords: coords)
turnLocations.append(coords)
```

And it is defined at the top like this :

```
var turnLocations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
```

And cleared with

```
turnLocations = []
```

Whenever the user resets the coordinates on the application (with a reset button)
The start button is added whenever there are no annotations

```
if(turnLocations.count < 1){ //if start isn't there already, it creates it
makeAnnotation(givenTitle: "Start", pointCoords: userCoords)
turnLocations.append(userCoords)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userCoords, latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

and userCoords is defined with this once userLocation is updated (with the built in location manager method)

```
userCoords = mapView.userLocation.coordinate
```

Comment: I’d suggest showing us how `turnLocations` is built. Or perhaps print out the coordinates of `turnLocations` and confirm it is what you think it is. There are some edge cases with `MKPolyline` strange behavior, but on the basis of what’s shared thus far, we don’t know if it’s that, or, more likely, just some issue with the population of `turnLocations`. We need the [bare minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but without diving into the gory details of your code. So share `turnLocations` with us.

Comment: @Rob I tried to do what you asked, did that give you enough information? Or was that too much?

Comment: @Rob sorry about that, didn't know that about the Xcode tag, I'll print out the mapView.overlays and turnLocations in the polyline function and edit it in when I can. (In class right now)

Comment: With a map with annotations that looks like this: <https://imgur.com/a/MqI5Ack> , the mapView.overlays printed `[<MKPolyline: 0x600000d540a0>]` and the locations printed were `[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -1.197754045278998e-06, longitude: -0.00022158450201459345), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.00030902054875525664, longitude: -0.0002335620426663354), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.00019164065039944944, longitude: 0.00014013722557137953)]`

Comment: That’s a good [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> the locations printed were `[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -1.197754045278998e-06, longitude: -0.00022158450201459345), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.00030902054875525664, longitude: -0.0002335620426663354), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.00019164065039944944, longitude: 0.00014013722557137953)]`

The polyline is just getting confused by that first datapoint at a latitude and longitude of 0, 0.

Consider:

```
let coordinates = [
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -1.197754045278998e-06, longitude: -0.00022158450201459345),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.00030902054875525664, longitude: -0.0002335620426663354),
    CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.00019164065039944944, longitude: 0.00014013722557137953)
]

let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: coordinates, count: coordinates.count)
mapView.addOverlay(polyline)
mapView.setVisibleMapRect(polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
```

That yields:

[image]

If you change that first one to something, else, e.g. `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0000001, longitude: 0.0000001)`, then it works fine:

[image]

Clearly `MKPolylineRenderer` is just confused by the 0, 0 coordinates. But if you use practical, real world coordinates that an end user is likely to be at, then it works fine.

Frankly, none of these data points look quite right. You’d generally express latitudes and longitudes in values between -180 and 180, but these are all right around zero, themselves, in the ocean off the coast of Africa.

So, if your concern is that the map view doesn’t handle the degenerate 0, 0 scenario right, feel free to [post a bug report](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome). If you think you’re going to encounter the 0, 0 and related scenarios in your app, I’d suggest you add a test for 0 latitude and/or longitude values and handle accordingly (e.g. use a tiny, non-zero value).

Comment: So from what I could tell, based on what you said, the 0,0 on the dot coordinate causes problems for mapkit? And the reason these data points look wrong is because I hadn't set my spoofed location in the simulator and the "start" is based on used location, therefore setting it to the 0,0 default.

Comment: Yes on both counts. For location stuff, testing on physical device is almost always better. The simulator does a decent job, but isn’t identical to how it works on an iOS device.